# bookmark-jump to a hidden part of a buffer

Tags: bookmarks, outline-mode, outline, visibility

In elisp buffers, I use `outline-mode` in order to manage headings similarly as in `org-mode`. But when I jump to a bookmark which points to a hidden part of a buffer (because it is below a folded heading), the point ends up at the lowest visible heading which contains the bookmark position.

How can I unfold the corresponding part of the buffer and jump to the actual position of the buffer?

In `org-mode` however, the problem does not occur: we have the desired behavior.

Comment: When you say, "In `org-mode`...the problem does not occur", what do you mean? When you do what in Org mode?

Comment: I mean: when I jump to a bookmark which points to a hidden place in an org-mode buffer, then the corresponding part unfolds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then you can add a **`bmkp-jump`** tag to any bookmark, to carry out any action just after that particular bookmark location is jumped to.

Give this tag a value that is a function, which then is called
whenever the tagged bookmark is visited.  Any Lisp-readable
function value is allowed: a symbol or a lambda expression.

For example, to display `Hello!` when a bookmark is visited you
can use this on that bookmark in the bookmark-list display:

```
T v bmkp-jump RET (lambda () (message "Hello!"))
```

That prompts you for the name of the bookmark to add that jump-function to as the value of tag `bmkp-jump`.

`T v` is bound in the bookmark-list display to command `bmkp-set-tag-value`. Elsewhere, the command is bound to `C-x p t v`. It adds a value to a tag that has none, or it changes the current value of a tag.

The function that is the value of a `bmkp-jump` tag is called just
after the the standard hook `bookmark-after-jump-hook` is invoked.
You can use this tag to invoke functions that are specific to
individual bookmarks; bookmarks can thus have their own, extra
jump functions.

So you just need a function that unfolds/unhides the current bit of text that you want to show. Use that in place of the function shown above. Try function `outline-show-entry`, for example.